# How to get React children from Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme

I've implemented a "slot" system in React from this article: [Vue Slots in React](https://medium.com/@srph/react-imitating-vue-slots-eab8393f96fd). However, I'm running into trouble when trying to test the component due to a "mismatch" between the Enzyme wrapper's children and React's children.

This is the function to get a "slot" child from React `children`. The function works as expected within a app component when provided with the `children` prop, but doesn't work during testing as the "children" isn't the same format as `React.children`.

```js
const getSlot = (children, slot) => {
  if (!children) return null;

  if (!Array.isArray(children)) {
    return children.type === slot ? children : null;
  }

  // Find the applicable React component representing the target slot
  return children.find((child) => child.type === slot);
};
```

The `TestComponent` isn't directly used in the tests, but is intended to show an example of how the "slots" would be implemented in a component.

```
const TestComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const slot = getSlot(children, TestComponentSlot);

  return (
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="permanentContent">Permanent Content</div>
      {slot && <div id="optionalSlot">{slot}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

const TestComponentSlot = () => null;
TestComponent.Slot = TestComponentSlot;
```

This is the basics of the tests I am trying to write. Essentially, creating a super basic component tree and then checking if the component's children contained the expected "slot" component. However, the `getSlot` function **always** returns `null` as the input isn't the same as the input provided by React `children` when used within the app.

```
it("Finds slots in React children", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <div>
      <TestComponent.Slot>Test</TestComponent.Slot>
    </div>
  );

  // Unsure how to properly get the React children to test method.
  //   Below are some example that don't work...

  // None of these approaches returns React children like function expects.
  //   Some return null and other return Enzyme wrappers.
  const children = wrapper.children();
  const { children } = wrapper.instance();
  const children = wrapper.children().instance();

  // TODO: Eventually get something I can put into function
  const slot = getSlot(children, TestComponentSlot);
});
```

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that when you're using enzyme's `children()` method it returns `ShallowWrapper`[[1](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/children.html#returns)]. In order to get the children as a React component you have to get them directly from the props method.

So, derive the children in this way:

```js
const children = wrapper.props().children;
```

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/enzyme-children-instance-eeq8e).

Comment: I believe I tried this as well at one point, but if you examine the output you'll notice that `wrapper.children().instance()` evaluates to `null`, which also is the output of the `getSlot` function (because the children passed is `null`). So this doesn't actually properly get the children or test the function :(.

Comment: @Kendall Got it, I've edited the answer and fixed sandbox.

Comment: @teimurgan Well that makes me feel rather silly! Thanks!